# Find the wrong number in the given series

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

[image]

I found this question in an Indian Highschool Reasoning Olympiad.
I tried  looking for any relation using powers of 2 but failed.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *wrong number*. Adapting its definition and our reasoning, we could make an argument about either of the proposed answers to be the right one : (42 is wrong because it is divisable by 7, 88 is wrong because all its digits are the same, 150 is wrong because it is divible by 5, 264 is wrong it is higher than 2^8...)

Comment: @Eargalo I understand that very well but that is all I know too but still I expect an answer as it was given to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86130/86943 because I feel they both are some sort of same question and lack same thing that is unique answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the "wrong" number in the sequence is

> (C) 150

Reasoning

> The $n$th term in the sequence is $n^3+n^2+2n$ except for **150** which should instead be $5^3 + 5^2 + 10 = 160$